# Will I lose much by buying a spray gun not suitable for water-based materials?

Tags: wood, painting, paint, spraying

Looking around for a spray gun for my woodworking projects, I've found [this one](http://www.spraygunsdirect.co.uk/product.php?tid=79&products_id=6399). This spray gun perfectly fits a couple of my requirements, so I'm seriously considering buying it.

However, I'm in doubt because of one thing that is mentioned in the description:

**NOT SUITABLE FOR WATERBASED MATERIALS**

And since I'm a total newbie in painting, I've decided to ask a couple of questions here:

- What are pros and cons of water-based vs solvent-based paints?
- Will I lose much by having a spray gun not suitable for water-based materials?

Comment: Contains rustable parts? Nozzle clogs due to latex?

Comment: what type of painting jobs do you want to do? That will make a difference in what type of sprayer to use.

Comment: @shirlockhomes, I will use it mostly for painting small or medium-sized wooden parts (say, shelf), lacquer.

Comment: @FiascoLabs, I have no idea.

Comment: If you are only going to use lacquer, a small air powered half pint gun would be fine. the same type you would use to shoot auto paints. These air sprayers will not shoot heavy based products like latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never got an answer so I will give you a simple one. I'm not a painter and just have a small amount of general knowledge...

> And since I'm a total newbie in painting, I've decided to ask a couple
>   of questions here:
>
> - What are pros and cons of water-based vs solvent-based paints?
> - Will I lose much by having a spray gun not suitable for water-based materials?

Pros and cons of water-based vs solvent-based? Well a simple answer would be that water-based is easier to work with, easier to clean up, better for the environment, and healthier. Solvent-based is tougher to work with and clean up, not so good for the environment, but generally considered better and more durable. Often most professional or factory finishes are solvent-based.